# auto closing bootstrap alerts after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ajax form that submits data into a database, and it uses bootstrap alerts for when it has been successful, I would like the alerts to close after a period of time has passed, but this needs to happen everytime.

For example if I load the form and make some changes and press submit it will show the success alert and then close, if I then submit the form again for example I forgot to change something perhaps, it will show the alert again, but this time it doesn't close.

How can I get the alert to show and close everytime?

I've provided an example with a hardcoded alert in the page, this is however written into the page using javascript, I couldn't figure out a way to provide a full example with working ajax code that showed the success alert with no back end PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap Alerts</title>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body class="bg-dark text-white">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="container-fluid mt-4">
            <p>Example Form</p>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form action="process_add_task.php" method="post" class="row form-horizontal align-items-start" role="form">
                    <input name="task_id" type="hidden" value="1" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="col-sm-12 mx-auto"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Success</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.notify.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, 1000);
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**$(this).hide();**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: what's this?is this an answer?

Comment: like what? remove () removes hide () simply style will change

Comment: explain what you did

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @UlasoftKoinotUz Unfortunately this doesn't work, well it kinda does, both remove() and hide() work when the alert is already in the page as html.  But if the alert is written to the page after the page has loaded the alert doesn't close it just stays there forever until I manually close it.